# Tensor product with endomorphism ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a commutative ring, $M$ a $k$-module and $k\longrightarrow A$ a $k$-algebra. Is it true that
$$A\otimes_k\operatorname{End}_k(M)\cong\operatorname{End}_A(A\otimes_kM)?$$
If not, under what conditions is it true? I know it is, provided $M$ is finite free over $k$ as can be seen by matrix considerations.

Also, does $$\operatorname{End}_k(M)\otimes_k\operatorname{End}_k(N)\cong\operatorname{End}_k(M\otimes_kN)$$ hold?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197993/endomorphism-algebra-of-the-tensor-product-of-modules)?